# Best way to save data for re-use off an voxel editor

Tags: c++, opengl, voxel

i'm planning on building a voxel editor (c++ and opengl) for personal use and i want to re-use the objects i build in later projects. The problem i came along is, i'm not sure whats the best way to save voxel data to files. I googled many sites and came across 'save as octree' and 'save as BSP tree' which one is better in your opinion and why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Field3D](http://opensource.imageworks.com/?p=field3d), it's used by the biggest and best in the CG industry to store voxel data for fluidics simulations.  All open-source of course.

Comment: Just by interest, do you happen to know how big voxel sets are used by the biggest and best in the CG industry? Are we talking like millions^3?

Comment: Once you factor in time, yes.  Usually the grids are adaptive (but max constrained), but then the simulations may go for minutes.  The Field3D format is designed for *giant* files, so data is pre-fetched from disk/discarded from memory dynamically, that's the main reason why it is so liked.

Comment: after reading a bit about that Field3D thing i find this very usefull. Thanks cbamber85 for providing this link.